# Log scale of y-axis is still very small

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, map, logarithmic-scale, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to use `LogPlot` of Mathematica to rewrite only y-axis (not x-axis) of the plot as log scale. But the y-axis is still very small.

By the following code

```
r[a_] := 324/25 Exp[-((
 2 (3 - a) (3 + a) (((-(1/4) + (-3 + a)/(
      2 (3 + a))) (1 + (
      2 (3 + a))/(-3 + a)))/(3 + a)))/(
 3 (-3 + a))) - 1.1792686931524656]
```

We obtain the plot

[image]

Then, to produce y-axis in log scale and by using `LogPlot` in Mathematica, we obtain

```
LogPlot[r[a], {a, -2.996, -2.98}, PlotStyle -> {RGBColor["#FF0000"], Thickness[0.008], Line},AspectRatio -> 3/4, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Still we see that the y-axis is very small. Is there any solution to remove smallness of y-axis using the log scale?

POINT: We would like to keep the x-axis in the present range.

Comment: It's small because the output of your function ``r[a_]`` is small. It's plotting the correct values. What else were you expecting?

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

r[a_] := 324/
   25  Exp[-((2  (3 - a)  (3 + 
           a)  (((-(1/4) + (-3 + a)/(2  (3 + a)))  (1 + (2  (3 + a))/(-3 + 
                  a)))/(3 + a)))/(3  (-3 + a))) - 1.1792686931524656]
```

Specify the desired [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)

```
Manipulate[
 LogPlot[r[a], {a, -2.996, -2.98},
  PlotRange -> pltRng,
  PlotStyle -> {RGBColor["#FF0000"], Thickness[0.008]},
  AspectRatio -> 3/4,
  ImageSize -> 300,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Black],
 {{pltRng, Automatic, "PlotRange"}, 
   {Automatic, {1.*^-100, 1.5*^-44}, {1.*^-140, 1.*^-40}}}]
```

[image]